# Angular JS nested ngRepeat loop how to break after maxRows are crossed the limit?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the below json structure stored in resultData:

```
{
    "ParentObjects": [
        {
            "objId": "A1",
            "ChildObjects": [
                {
                    "description": "child object1"
                },
                {
                    "description": "child object2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "objId": "A2",
            "ChildObjects": [
                {
                    "description": "child object3"
                },
                {
                    "description": "child object4"
                },
                {
                    "description": "child object5"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "objId": "A3",
            "ChildObjects": [
                {
                    "description": "child object6"
                },
                {
                    "description": "child object7"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have 2 ng-repeat in my html as follows:

```html
<table>
 <tbody ng-repeat="parentObj in resultData">
   <tr ng-repeat="childObj in parentObj.ChildObjects">
  <td>{{childObj.description}}</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to restrict the number of <tr> that will be displayed to 4 irrespective of number of parent and child in them. I know limitTo but it will apply only on inner loop and will not take account previously rendered rows by earlier parent objects.

Is it possible to restrict the rows considering/counting all child objects?

Answer (score 2):

You can limit with limitTo in ng-repeat

```html
<table>
 <tbody ng-repeat="parentObj in resultData | limitTo:4">
   <tr ng-repeat="childObj in parentObj.ChildObjects ">
  <td>{{childObj.description}}</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: No, this will not solve the problem. As I have to also count total rows rendered and limitTo will only apply on inner tr rendering.

Comment: Can you use limitTo in resultData please. It can work .

Answer (score 0):

LimitTo will not work here, because each ng-repeat iteration creates a new scope and LimitTo will be restricted to that specific array or list('ChildObjects').

http://plnkr.co/edit/DrJpf4xiPq4AwtMKUQaU

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <table>
      <tbody ng-repeat="parentObj in resultData.ParentObjects">
        <tr ng-repeat="childObj in parentObj.ChildObjects | limitTo:4">
          <td>{{childObj.description}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

you can achieve this by setting index for each item in childObjects array.

http://plnkr.co/edit/pUQAvjkJXkn4JRBx1efh

```
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <body ng-app="plunker">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <table ng-init="SetIndex()">
            <tbody ng-repeat="parentObj in resultData.ParentObjects">
              <tr ng-if="childObj.index < 4" ng-repeat="childObj in parentObj.ChildObjects">
                <td>{{childObj.description}}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
         </div>
  </body>

</html>

$scope.SetIndex = function () {
        var item = 0;
        angular.forEach($scope.resultData.ParentObjects, function (value, key) {
            angular.forEach(value.ChildObjects, function (value1, key) {
                value1.index = item;
                item = item + 1;
            });
        });
    }
```